# How to display content of multiple QSqlTableModels in one QTableView?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I have a *MySql* table, let's call it *x*:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    Id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    A int unsigned NOT NULL,
    B int,
    FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES y(Id)
);
```

And then I have another table, let's call it *y*:

```
CREATE TABLE y (
    Id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    First varchar(255),
    Last varchar(255)
);
```

I want to display table *x* in one *QTableView* and in place of column *A* from table *x* I want to display columns *First* and *Last* from table *y* from row whose *Id* is equal to *A* from table *x*.

Do you have any ideas? Let me know if my explanation is not clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QSqlQueryModel` with sql join query:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery("SELECT x.Id, y.First, y.Last, x.B FROM x "
                "LEFT JOIN y ON x.A = y.Id");

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
view->show();
```

Comment: I'm wondering are these kind of views editable? I mean is it possible to edit tableview contents and changes committed to database automatically?